# Can MSSQL be made work with current PHP 5.6 & IIS 8

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, sqlsrv

I know that the newer SQLSVR is recommended, but is SQLSVR an absolute 'must' on a server running IIS version 8.5?

The reason for this question is that I have been ask to migrate an existing website from an old server to a new one. I was hoping to avoid or minimize modifying the PHP code and that site has the MSSQL component.

Please excuse if this question seems like a repeat but, I have searched and I just cannot find a clear statement saying that MSSQL is dead.

Thank you for your help and patience is this question is a repeat.

Answer (score 0):

If you use functionality of MSSQL in PHP, then yes, you should use Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server (SQLSRV).

A quick search on Google like *sqlsrv vs mssql* leads nice information about comparison and why you should use sqlsrv (at least in my guess).

For IIS version, although I have never been used sqlsrv driver on IIS 8.5, there is no source I found indicates that you cannot use this driver on that version. So, it should be fine with your IIS.

Comment: Thank you Alalp. 

The web site that I have been asked to migrate is quite old, the original creator long since gone. 

I have hoped to migrate a website without too much edit of existing PHP code but there is much use of the MSSQL API.